# How to set broken bar order after grouping the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The code example below draws a broken barh diagram with a list of persons which joined and left a music band during a period of time:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

result = pd.DataFrame([['Bill', 1972, 1974],
                       ['Bill', 1976, 1978],
                       ['Bill', 1967, 1971],
                       ['Danny', 1969, 1975],
                       ['Danny', 1976, 1977],
                       ['James', 1971, 1972],
                       ['Marshall', 1967, 1975]],
                      columns=['Person', 'Year_start', 'Year_left'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

names = sorted(result['Person'].unique())

colormap = plt.get_cmap('plasma')
slicedColorMap = colormap(np.linspace(0, 1, len(names)))

height = 0.5
for y, (name, g) in enumerate(result.groupby('Person')):
    ax.broken_barh(list(zip(g['Year_start'],
                            g['Year_left']-g['Year_start'])),
                   (y-height/2, height),
                   facecolors=slicedColorMap[y]
                   )

ax.set_ylim(0-height, len(names)-1+height)
ax.set_xlim(result['Year_start'].min()-1, result['Year_left'].max()+1)
ax.set_yticks(range(len(names)), names)

ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

The output result is this diagram:
[image]

I need to order the bars (along with the Persons in y axis) by 'Year_start' and 'Year_left', both in ascending order.

I know how to aggregate and order values in dataframe after the data is grouped, and that I should reset index afterwards:

```
sorted_result = result.groupby('Person').agg({'Year_start': min, 'Year_left': max})
sorted_result = sorted_result.sort_values(['Year_start', 'Year_left'], ascending=[True, True]).reset_index()
print(sorted_result)
```

But I am having a hard time to embed this sorting into existing "for in" loop when drawing the ax.broken_barh (also because as I understood it is not possible to perform "sort_values" with "groupby" using "agg" in a single iteration).
Is this sorting possible in this script at all or I should completely reconsider the script structure?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIIC, all you need to do is use `sort=False` when using `groupby()` and previously sort the dataframe in your desired way. The rest of the code can remain the same:

EDIT: However, due to the sorting being quite specific and not easily covered in `sort_values()`, I suggest to do in an external dataframe and then merging it back to the original dataframe to sort it.

```
result = pd.DataFrame([['Bill', 1972, 1974],
                       ['Bill', 1976, 1978],
                       ['Bill', 1967, 1971],
                       ['Danny', 1969, 1975],
                       ['Danny', 1976, 1977],
                       ['James', 1971, 1972],
                       ['Marshall', 1967, 1975]],
                      columns=['Person', 'Year_start', 'Year_left'])

sorter = result.groupby('Person').agg({'Year_start':'min','Year_left':'max'})\
    .sort_values(['Year_start','Year_left'],
                 ascending=[True,True])\
        .index.to_frame().\
            assign(sorter = range(result['Person'].nunique()))\
                .set_index('Person').to_dict()['sorter']
                                                               
result['sorter'] = result['Person'].map(sorter)
result = result.sort_values('sorter',ascending=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

colormap = plt.get_cmap('plasma')
slicedColorMap = colormap(np.linspace(0, 1, result['Person'].nunique()))

height = 0.5
names = []
for y, (name, g) in enumerate(result.groupby('Person',sort=False)): #Here I'm using sort=False to avoid groupby from sorting it differently
    print(name)
    ax.broken_barh(list(zip(g['Year_start'],
                            g['Year_left']-g['Year_start'])),
                   (y-height/2, height),
                   facecolors=slicedColorMap[y]
                   )
    names.append(name)
```

The rest of the code remains the same. This outputs:

I'm also making a small improvement by not statically defining `names` which will later be passed, but rather creating the list as the loop goes by so the name will always match the bar. That's why I'm also using `result['Person'].nunique()` rather than `len(names)`

EDIT: Code edited based on discussion with OP
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6epWQ.png

Comment: Thank you!
That's amazing!
I spent so much time figuring this out (I'm new to python).
Regarding "names" I thought about this too (that technically it is possible to apply names in loop), but didn't knew about "append" method.
Thank you a lot!

Comment: Happy to help! Python can be tricky at times, but if you are new to python already working on this, it's awesome!

Comment: Thank you!
Btw, I just noticed a strange behavior: "Marshall" and "Bill" should swap positions in diagram, because of the order by "Year_left" ascending.
Marshall left the band earlier than Bill, so he should go first.
It can be fixed by changing the ascending order of "Year_left" column in "result" to "ascending=[True, False]" - which technically is vice versa.

Comment: Good catch, I actually completely ignored the `Year_left` criteria, but you can definitely add it to the sort_values() as well as any other variables you'd like to include in the future.

Comment: Yep, I added but nothing changed, which is strange =)
It only changes to correct sorting order when I change ascending=False for "Year_left" column, which contradicts to the order shown on diagram.

result = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['Person', 'Year_start', 'Year_left']).sort_values(['Year_start', 'Year_left'],ascending=[True, True]).reset_index()

Comment: Ah alright, I thought it did solve it, let me have a look and edit my code with a follow-up comment once it's been updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253954/discussion-between-celius-stingher-and-muted-buddy).

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there :-) You already have the names sorted by earliest start and earliest end. You just need to change the Person column to categorical with the order that you received and then do the barh plotting by adding sort_values('Person') before grouping. The updated code is below. Added comments to make it easy. Hope this is what you are you are looking for...

Please note - I think you are using matplotlib 3.2 or earlier. So, set_yticks() works. But, it is deprecated in newer version. Have split it into set_yticks() and set_yticklabels() as is required in newer versions. Also, changed names to sorted_result.Person.to_list() so the labels are correctly aligned.

```
result = pd.DataFrame([['Bill', 1972, 1974],
                       ['Bill', 1976, 1978],
                       ['Bill', 1967, 1971],
                       ['Danny', 1969, 1975],
                       ['Danny', 1976, 1977],
                       ['James', 1971, 1972],
                       ['Marshall', 1967, 1975]],
                      columns=['Person', 'Year_start', 'Year_left'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

names = sorted(result['Person'].unique())

colormap = plt.get_cmap('plasma')
slicedColorMap = colormap(np.linspace(0, 1, len(names)))

height = 0.5

## NEW ADDED CODE ##
## This is your code.. get the sorted_result
sorted_result = result.groupby('Person').agg({'Year_start': min, 'Year_left': max})
sorted_result = sorted_result.sort_values(['Year_start', 'Year_left'], ascending=[True, True]).reset_index()

## Change Person to categorical, so that, when you sort it, it will be in the order you need
## Notice that I am using sorted_result.Person.to_list(), basically sort order as you need
result['Person'] = pd.Categorical(
    result['Person'], 
    categories=sorted_result.Person.to_list(), 
    ordered=True
)

## Here, added sort_values('Person') before grouping...
for y, (name, g) in enumerate(result.sort_values('Person').groupby('Person')):
    ax.broken_barh(list(zip(g['Year_start'],
                            g['Year_left']-g['Year_start'])),
                   (y-height/2, height),
                   facecolors=slicedColorMap[y]
                   )

ax.set_ylim(0-height, len(names)-1+height)
ax.set_xlim(result['Year_start'].min()-1, result['Year_left'].max()+1)
ax.set_yticks(range(len(sorted_result.Person.to_list())))  ##Changed name
ax.set_yticklabels(sorted_result.Person.to_list())  ## Changed name

ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you!
Using "pd.Categorical" is something I definitely must to learn.
Good point on "set_yticklabels()" as well, I didn't know that.
Thanks!